# Ball collisions getting stuck together when colliding canvas html 5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having a problem with collision detection between two balls.
Only occasionally the balls will merge,they usually behave as they should.
I had the same problem with the border of the canvas but was able to fix it.
I cant seem to figure out how to apply the logic the circles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see below for the code block in question. also the complete snippet.

```
//Intersect function takes a ball as a perameter
        //ball will be the the object used to test if the two are touching.

        function intersect(ball,ball1) {
        //the x and y cordinates of the first ball are subtracted from the test ball and stored
        //in productX and productY
        dx = ball1.x - ball.x;
        dy = ball1.y - ball.y;
        //pythagoras theorem is used to get the distance between both center points of each circle.
        distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        //A condition is used to check if the distance between both bencer point of each circle
        //is less than or equal to the sum of both radii the circles are touching.
        //the result is p[rinted out to the console
        if (distance < ball1.r + ball.r) {


          collision_angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
          magnitude_1 = Math.sqrt(ball.xvel*ball.xvel+ball.yvel*ball.yvel);
          magnitude_2 = Math.sqrt(ball1.xvel*ball1.xvel+ball1.yvel*ball1.yvel);

          direction_1 = Math.atan2(ball.yvel, ball.xvel);
          direction_2 = Math.atan2(ball1.yvel, ball1.xvel);

          new_xvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.cos(direction_1-collision_angle);
          new_yvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_1-collision_angle);
          new_xvel_2 = magnitude_2 * Math.cos(direction_2-collision_angle);
          new_yvel_2 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_2-collision_angle);

          final_xvel_1 = ((ball.mass-ball1.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass+ball1.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);
          final_xvel_2 = ((ball.mass+ball.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass-ball.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);

          final_yvel_1 = new_yvel_1;
          final_yvel_2 = new_yvel_2;

          ball.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
          ball.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
          ball1.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;
          ball1.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;

        } 
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas</title>

    <style type="text/css">
  canvas {
   border: 1px solid grey; 
  }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas-for-ball"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  // Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
  // Get a 2D context for the canvas.
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  function init(){
            canvas.width = 500;
            canvas.height = 500;
   
        }
        init();
        
        //ball object
  class Ball {
   constructor(x,y,r,xvel,yvel,mass){
    this.x =x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r =r;
    this.xvel = xvel;
    this.yvel = yvel;
                this.mass = mass;
    //angle defining spin and sections of ball
    this.theta = 0;
    //for the sections of the ball
    this.theta2 = 0;
    //for he amount of sections needed
    this.seventh = (Math.PI*2)/7
    //to control the amount of spin the ball has
    this.thetaInc = 0.0129;
    //For gravity
    this.gravity = 1;
    this.friction = .01;
   }
   drop(){
    //Gravity
    this.yvel += this.gravity*1.9;
    //friction
    this.xvel = this.xvel - (this.xvel*this.friction);
   }
            draw(){
    
    // Update the y location.
    this.x += this.xvel;
    this.y += this.yvel;
    

    //draw circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.stroke();
    //fill the circle
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color ;
    ctx.fill();
    //draw inner circle of ball
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r*.9,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.stroke();
    //spin control
    this.theta += this.thetaInc;
    //loop for adding sections to pie
    for( var n = 0; n < 7; ++n) {  // add loop to draw radii
     this.theta2 = this.theta + n * this.seventh;
     ctx.moveTo( this.x, this.y);
     ctx.lineTo( this.x + this.r*Math.cos(this.theta2), this.y + this.r*Math.sin(this.theta2));
     }
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();   
   }
            move(){ 
    if(this.y >= canvas.height - this.r){
     this.y = canvas.height - this.r;
     this.yvel =-this.yvel;
     }else if(this.y<=0+this.r){
       this.y = this.r;
       this.yvel = -this.yvel;
     }
     //to reverse the direction of the ball when hitting walls
     if((this.xvel<0 && this.yvel >0) && this.thetaInc <0){
      this.thetaInc = -1*this.thetaInc;
     }
     else if((this.xvel <0 && this.yvel>0) && this.thetaInc >0){
      this.thetaInc = -1*this.thetaInc
     }
     else if((this.xvel >0 && this.yvel >0) && this.thetaInc >0){
      this.thetaInc = -1 * this.thetaInc;
     }
     else if((this.xvel > 0 && this.yvel < 0)&& this.thetaInc <0){
      this.thetaInc = -1 * this.thetaInc;
     }
    
     if(this.x>=canvas.width-this.r){
      this.x = canvas.width - this.r;
      this.xvel = -this.xvel;
        }else if(this.x<=this.r){
       this.x = this.r;
       this.xvel = -this.xvel;
        } 
    
   }
   resize(){
        var that = this;
        that.up = true;
        that.r = 20;
        that.increment = 1;
        that.ceiling = 50;
        function PerformCalc() {
          if (that.up == true && that.r <= that.ceiling) {
         that.r += that.increment
        
         if (that.r == that.ceiling) {
           that.up = false;
         }
          } else {
           that.up = false
           that.r -= that.increment;
        
           if (that.r == 20) {
          that.up = true;
           }
          }
        
        }
        setInterval(PerformCalc, 800);
          
         }

    
      
     
   setColour(){
    
        this.o = Math.round, this.rd = Math.random, this.s = 255;
     this.color =  'rgb(' + this.o(this.rd()*this.s) + ',' + this.o(this.rd()*this.s) + ',' + this.o(this.rd()*this.s) +')';
    
     
     
   }
            

        }
   
   //Intersect function takes a ball as a perameter
   //ball will be the the object used to test if the two are touching.
   
   function intersect(ball,ball1) {
   //the x and y cordinates of the first ball are subtracted from the test ball and stored
   //in productX and productY
      dx = ball1.x - ball.x;
      dy = ball1.y - ball.y;
   //pythagoras theorem is used to get the distance between both center points of each circle.
      distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
   //A condition is used to check if the distance between both bencer point of each circle
   //is less than or equal to the sum of both radii the circles are touching.
   //the result is p[rinted out to the console
      if (distance < ball1.r + ball.r) {
        
              
              collision_angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
              magnitude_1 = Math.sqrt(ball.xvel*ball.xvel+ball.yvel*ball.yvel);
              magnitude_2 = Math.sqrt(ball1.xvel*ball1.xvel+ball1.yvel*ball1.yvel);

              direction_1 = Math.atan2(ball.yvel, ball.xvel);
              direction_2 = Math.atan2(ball1.yvel, ball1.xvel);

              new_xvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.cos(direction_1-collision_angle);
              new_yvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_1-collision_angle);
              new_xvel_2 = magnitude_2 * Math.cos(direction_2-collision_angle);
              new_yvel_2 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_2-collision_angle);

              final_xvel_1 = ((ball.mass-ball1.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass+ball1.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);
              final_xvel_2 = ((ball.mass+ball.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass-ball.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);

              final_yvel_1 = new_yvel_1;
              final_yvel_2 = new_yvel_2;

              ball.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
              ball.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
              ball1.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;
              ball1.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;
     
            } 
    }
    canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
     var clickX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
     var clickY = event.clientY- canvas.offsetTop;
     b1.x = clickX;
     b1.y = clickY;  
    });
  // Add a Javascript event listener to the keypress event.
  window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { 
   // Just log the event to the console.
   console.log(event);
  });

  //keypresses with jQuery
  $(document.body).on('keydown', function(e) {
   console.log(e.which);
   switch (e.which) {
    // key code for left arrow
    case 37:
    console.log('left arrow key pressed!');
    b1.xvel --;
    break;
    //keycode for up
    case 38:
    console.log('up key pressed');
    b1.yvel++;
    break;
    //key code for right
    case 39:
    console.log('right arrow key pressed!');
    b1.xvel++;
    break;
    //key code for down
    case 40:
    console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
    b1.yvel--;
    break;
    //key code for + key to increase spin
    case 107:
    console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
    b1.thetaInc += .001;
    break;
    //key code for - key to decrease spin
    case 109:
    console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
    b1.thetaInc -= .001;
    break;
   }
  });
 b1 = new Ball(200,200,40,10,10,5);
    b2 = new Ball(100,100,40,2,2,5);
 b1.resize();
 b2.resize();
    // A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
 function repeatme() {
  //clear canvas for each frame of the animation.
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
  // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
  b1.draw();
  
        b2.draw();
        b1.move();
  b1.drop();
  b1.setColour();
        b2.move();
        intersect(b1,b2);
  //put repeatme function into the animation frame and store it in animate
  animate =  window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme); 
 }
     // Get the animation going.
 repeatme();
   
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

---

You can click the screen to change the position of one of the balls to see the problem quicker.

Comment: When you detect a collision you should move both balls so that they do not overlap. Just setting the velocity does not guarantee the balls will separate. You also need to account  the movement from one frame to the next. The balls collide at some time during the last frame, so depending on when that contact was the balls may have moved apart by some distance, or the contact was at the end of the frame in which case they are just touching. Get the time of the collision (between the frames), move both balls away from each other, then move each the remaining time along the new path.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment yet so adding it here =/

What I am noticing is that once the problem happens, one of the balls appears to have an incorrect mass set as it will bounce and then move much more slowly through space than the other. Sometimes this will happen but they won't stick, however it seems like they almost always stick after the next collision occurs.

Still trying to wrap my head around *why* that is happening, but I think that it is probably related.

Comment: i have a gravity effect on one of the balls and they have different masses.

Comment: Both balls are resizing aswell

Comment: if (distance < ball1.r + ball.r) { ::: does this need to be less than or equal to? If I am understanding this section right then it would allow the edges of the balls to be inside of each other before "bouncing", which may be causing them to trigger additional collisions before their new vector takes them back away from each other? Not really sure, but I'll keep mulling it over as I have time

Comment: Basically is it possible that it is triggering the if less than more than once before processing that the balls have actually moved away from one another

Comment: I've tried <= but the same problem happens. Thank you for taking time out to have a look i appreciate it.

Comment: The collision detection might need an else-statement, handing cases where new velocities are set on previous calculation, but the balls are still intersecting next time the function is called.